# Rewriting a particular matrix as the product of two other matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 M_1, \dots , x_K M_K \end{pmatrix}, 
\end{align*}
where each $x_i$ is a scalar and each $M_i$ is a $p \times 1$ column vector. I would like to rewrite $A$ in the form
\begin{align*}
A = B M, 
\end{align*}
for some matrix $B$, where $M$ is the $p \times k$ matrix formed by putting the $M$ column vectors next to one another:
\begin{align*}
M = \begin{pmatrix} M_1, \dots, M_K \end{pmatrix}. 
\end{align*}
This seems doable, but I haven't been able to find $B$. What matrix $B$ will do the job? How do I find it?

Comment: Do you know what the dimensions of $B$ are? From there, you can try some guesses.

Comment: I can see that $B$ must be $p \times p$. But not sure where to go from there!

Comment: Doesn't look promising, right? Especially if $p \ne k$. Maybe you want to try $A = MB$?

Comment: Ah, I see — thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ may be written $BM$ for some $B$ iff $\ker M\subset\ker A,$ which is generally not true in your situation.

On the other hand,
$$A=MB\quad\text{for}\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1    & 0      & \ldots & 0      \\
0      & x_2    & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0      \\
0      & \ldots & 0      & x_K
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ah I see! This is very helpful. Thank you!